# How to avoid resolving a route in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, url-routing, new-operator

I'm developing a rails app with an admin section and a public section. In the public section I want to resolve only index and show routes

```
resources :services, :only => [:index, :show]
```

However, when I hit the standard URL for the new action it resolves to the show action with an id of 'new'. That is http://foo.com/services/new returns an error "Couldn't find Service with ID=new". Is there anyway I can tell rails NOT to resolve /services/new?

I've already tried

```
resources :services, :only => [:index, :show], :except => :new
```

and

```
resources :services, :except => :new, :only => [:index, :show]
```

without success.

ETA (by request):
My entire routes file (sans comments):

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :services, :only => [:index, :show]
  resources :packages,:only => [:index, :show]

  get "pages/home"
  get "pages/about"
  get "pages/help"

  root :to => 'packages#index'

  namespace "admin" do
    get "pages/home"
    get "pages/about"
    get "pages/help"

    resources :services
    match "/services/:id/add_to_package/:package_id" => "services#add_package",       :as => :add_package_to_service,      :via => :post, :id => /\d+/, :package_id => /\d+/
    match "/services/:id/remove_from_package/:package_id" => "services#remove_package", :as => :remove_package_from_service, :via => :post, :id => /\d+/, :package_id => /\d+/

    resources :packages 
    match "/packages/:id/add_service/:service_id" => "packages#add_service",       :as => :add_service_to_package,      :via => :post, :id => /\d+/, :service_id => /\d+/
    match "/packages/:id/remove_service/:service_id" => "packages#remove_service", :as => :remove_service_from_package, :via => :post, :id => /\d+/, :service_id => /\d+/

    resources :users

    root :to => 'pages#home'
  end
end
```

Comment: I'd use a `redirect` in the routes file or in the controller because the url is normally taken into account

Comment: Can you post the entire routes file?

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at this the wrong way, but by "not resolving a route" you mean return a 404? In production mode, if you are doing Service.find(params[:id), then "Couldn't find Service with ID=new" is going to be replaced with a 404.... so it's serving the same basic purpose, telling the world this page doesn't exist.

Comment: It's possible I'm getting side-tracked from my main project, but I'm trying to get past a testing problem using rspec - specifically, I'm trying to get `{ :get => "/service_packages/new" }.should_not be_routable` to pass (without breaking the other tests)

Answer (score 1):

You can try to putting a constraint on your `:id` param

```
resources :services, :constraints => {:id => /\d+/}, :only => [:index, :show]
```

This is assuming your `:id`s are all number based.

I had a similar situation with a redirect vs resource collision, this fixed it.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm dealing with number and textual ids, though I think I'll pursue this avenue further...

Comment: I thought I had a solution with negative look-ahead matching `resources :services, :constraints => {:id => /(?!new)\w+/}, :only => [:index, :show]` but that's not doing the trick either. I can get it work work in the console, but only using start/end anchors, which aren't allowed in route matching for some reason.